# How do I find similar announcement by title and description?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

I need to compare one announcement with an array of other announcements and find which ones are similar.
Two announcements are considered similar if they have at least one same word in title and description.
They looks like :

```
[
   {title: "Test", description: "hello", id: 22},
   {title: "Test two", description: "hi", id: 49},
   {title: "Test three", description: "hello there", id: 100},
   {title: "Test four", description: "oh", id: 129},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
const findSimilarAnnouncements = (announcements, targetAnnouncement) => {
  const targetTitleWords = targetAnnouncement.title.split(' ');
  const targetDescriptionWords = targetAnnouncement.description.split(' ');
  
  return announcements.filter(({ title, description }) => {
    const titleWords = title.split(' ');
    const descriptionWords = description.split(' ');

    const isTitleSimilar = targetTitleWords
      .some(word => titleWords.includes(word));
    const isDescriptionSimilar = targetDescriptionWords
      .some(word => descriptionWords.includes(word));

    return isTitleSimilar && isDescriptionSimilar;
  });
};
```

Comment: It works but I need to collect simillar announcements in one array. Can you help?

Comment: I don't understand, they all are returned in one array. If not similar announcements are found, the array is empty